# I am getting this error "Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)" In Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, bulkinsert, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create a table in Azure Sql server with external data source from blob.I have the set the blob access level to Public Level - Container(anonymous read access for containers and blob). Can someone suggest that whether do I need to configure in SQL SERVER for enabling bulk insert? I am the server admin of this sql server.

Comment: what account will access SQL server? Will it be a windows AD or a SQL-Server account. Either way that account needs to have READWRITE access to whatever database your inserting data into from blob.

Comment: The SQL server will access the SQL Server account it has both read/write permission. I have installed Dbeaver in my Ubuntu machine and logged in to the SQL Server and running this statement.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017?

Comment: @PrishiKumar   Do you have any update?

Comment: i will check and update in few hours  thanks for the help

Comment: @PrishiKumar Any update？